# Compiling/using libjpeg in Windows for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dll, mingw, libjpeg

This question/answer will eventually serve as complete answer for this question: [How can I manipulate/rotate a JPEG image in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14586759/1666510) Since the answers given to that question are only useful if you have already done all of this below.

I followed the guide here: [Compiling libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652178/compiling-libjpeg)
(The accepted answer guide using MINGW32 Shell)

It doesn't work despite having downloaded a fresh copy:

```
$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/tmp/jpeg-9'
  CC       jaricom.lo
  CC       jcapimin.lo
jcapimin.c:127:1: error: conflicting types for 'jpeg_suppress_tables'
jcapimin.c:128:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can't matc
h an empty parameter name list declaration
In file included from jcapimin.c:22:0:
jpeglib.h:997:14: note: previous declaration of 'jpeg_suppress_tables' was here
make[1]: *** [jcapimin.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/tmp/jpeg-9'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

8d and 9 both do the same.

After making the change noted in this question: [Compile libjpeg with mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087749/compile-libjpeg-with-mingw)

> Add the following definition to the jconfig.h
>
> `#define HAVE_PROTOTYPES 1`

I get this output when making:

```
$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/tmp/jpeg-9'
  CC       jaricom.lo
In file included from jinclude.h:20:0,
                 from jaricom.c:17:
jconfig.h:5:24: warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive [enabled by def
ault]
  CC       jcapimin.lo
In file included from jinclude.h:20:0,
                 from jcapimin.c:21:
jconfig.h:5:24: warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive [enabled by def
ault]
jcapimin.c:127:1: error: conflicting types for 'jpeg_suppress_tables'
jcapimin.c:128:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can't matc
h an empty parameter name list declaration
In file included from jcapimin.c:22:0:
jpeglib.h:997:14: note: previous declaration of 'jpeg_suppress_tables' was here
make[1]: *** [jcapimin.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/tmp/jpeg-9'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then you have to run "autoheader" to fix this and make again.

It supposedly made but there is nothing in my build directory set by ./configure --prefix=/c/tmp/jpeg-9-build/

I found the libjpeg-9.dll in the .lib folder within the project directory.

Messy..Now the question is: How do I use it in Eclipse?

I have the exe's in the main directory, some exe's and the DLL in the .lib sub-directory but no .lib file - How do I go about importing these into an eclipse project so that I can call functions in the DLL?

`$ make install` gathered the files in the build directory.

I migrated the contents of the build directory into the working Eclipse project and linked the library and include paths:

[image: Directory tree for basic implementation of jpeglib in Eclipse]

I'm not sure if this is right for how I want to use it but it's something and it compiles. Next part: Calling functions out of the DLL?

Related to using compiled jpegtran.exe: [jpegtran.exe not correctly rotating image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14612809/1666510)

Trying to use libraries and compile in separate project: [Need help compiling jpegtran.c code from libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14631530/1666510)

Current issue: [Need help compiling jpegtran.c code from libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14631530/1666510)

Answer (score 1):

Your advice for updating the jconfig.h file to `#define HAVE_PROTOTYPES 1` is only a band-aid solution for a deeper problem: jconfig.h is corrupted and has incorrect `#undef` for many important items your compiler supports.

The proper way to work around this is to follow the install.txt advice to manually compile ckconfig.c and have it generate a jconfig.h for you, then proceed to make, and make install.